# How to use jQuery to get the attribute of class elements in continuous sequential order

Tags: jquery, class

I'm trying to get the attributes of class elements in a continuous and sequential order using jQuery.

I am showing a current image in one `div` and have a series of small images in a lower `div`.

I want to scroll through each of the small images and show them as the current image. It's working all except for making the small images the current image. I keep getting only one image as the current image. I've tried using Jquery's `.next()` and `.nextAll()` but keep getting `undefined` as a result.

Here is the code that's at issue:

```
var image = $('#small_images a:nth-child(n+1)').attr("rel");
```

This works to get only the first small image. I've tried using a lot of code such as the following:

```
var image = $('#small_images').nextAll('.small_image').attr('rel');
```

But I get the result undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

The full code is at https://jsfiddle.net/lawprac1/pLhxm254/2/

I've tried various lines of code, such as:

```
var image = $('#small_images').children().nextAll().find('.small_image:nth-child(n)').attr('rel');
```

But it keeps coming up as undefined.

Comment: The JSFiddle is at: https://jsfiddle.net/lawprac1/pLhxm254/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need a persistent variable that keeps track of which current image index you're on. From that, you can increment and extract the appropriate next index from the collection.

```
let i = 0;
function cycleImages() {
  var image = $('#small_images a:nth-child(n+1)').eq(i).attr("rel");
  i = (i + 1) % 3;
```

```js
let i = 0;
function cycleImages() {
  var image = $('#small_images a:nth-child(n+1)').eq(i).attr("rel");
  i = (i + 1) % 3;
  console.log(' image is ' + image);
  $('#current_image').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#current_image').html('<img width="370" src="' + image + '"/>');
    $('#current_image').fadeIn(300);
  });
}
setInterval(cycleImages, 2000);
```

```css
#image_gallery {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#current_image {
  width: 370px;
  height: 245px;
  //float:left;
  background: #CCC;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#current_image img {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#small_images {
  margin: 50px 20px 0 50px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  //float:right;
}

.small_image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small_image img {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#small_images ul {
  width: 360px;
  list-style: none;
}

#small_images ul li {
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_gallery">
  <div id="current_image">
    <img width="370" src="merch-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!--End current_image-->
  <div id="small_images">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image active" rel="merch-1.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-1.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image" rel="merch-2.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-2.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image" rel="merch-3.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-3.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!--End small_images-->
</div>
<!--End image_gallery-->
```

If it were me, I'd extract all the images at once on pageload instead of having to iterate through the DOM each time.

```js
let i = 0;
const images = [...$('#small_images a')].map(a => a.rel);
function cycleImages() {
  const image = images[i];
  i = (i + 1) % 3;
  console.log(' image is ' + image);
  $('#current_image').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#current_image').html('<img width="370" src="' + image + '"/>');
    $('#current_image').fadeIn(300);
  });
}
setInterval(cycleImages, 2000);
```

```css
#image_gallery {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#current_image {
  width: 370px;
  height: 245px;
  //float:left;
  background: #CCC;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#current_image img {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#small_images {
  margin: 50px 20px 0 50px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  //float:right;
}

.small_image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small_image img {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#small_images ul {
  width: 360px;
  list-style: none;
}

#small_images ul li {
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_gallery">
  <div id="current_image">
    <img width="370" src="merch-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!--End current_image-->
  <div id="small_images">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image active" rel="merch-1.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-1.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image" rel="merch-2.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-2.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="small_image" rel="merch-3.jpg">
          <img width="90" src="merch-3.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!--End small_images-->
</div>
<!--End image_gallery-->
```